# Nxlog pipe scheduled command output

Tags: hp-ux, nxlog

I'm trying to read the output of the `last` command in Nxlog. I would like to run `last` on the `utmp` file on regular intervals. In other words I want to schedule a shell command to run with a time interval and pipe the output as a log event. In yet other words I would like to have  `<Schedule>` clauses in a `im_exec` module but it seems that this is not possible so I'm trying something else (the example is for linux):

```
<Input sample_umtp_linux>
  Module im_null
  <Schedule>
    Every   1 sec
    Exec exec("/usr/bin/last", "-f", "/var/run/utmp");
  </Schedule>
</Input>

<Output out_debug>
    Module    om_file
    File      '<mydir>/debug.log'
</Output>

<Route processwtmp>
    Path      sample_umtp_linux => out_debug
</Route>
```

I don't get any error messages, but I don't get any output either. Is there some way to catch the output and feed it into the Nxlog routing?

(**Additional limitation:** I'm going to deploy the solution to Hp Ux, so my options are a bit limited in terms of available system tools. I'd like to depend as little as possible on things outside Nxlog itself.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for Linux that should've been rather obvious:

```
<Input sample_umtp_linux>
  Module im_exec
  Command <my_script_dir>/run_last_forever.sh
</Input>
```

And with a script, `run_last_forever.sh`, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    /usr/bin/last -f /var/run/utmp
    sleep 1
done
```

However, it seems that Nxlog might not be buildable for HP-UX after all. But that's a separate issue.